# Material-UI including an inline link with the label for Radio Buttons, checkboxes, etc

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to include a dynamic link inline with the label of a list of Material-UI radio buttons in a React app. When I implement the following code I see `[object Object]` in place of where I'd expect the Reference Docs link to show up.  What am I doing wrong?

```
referenceDocsLink(protocol) {
  return (
      <a
        className="Content-Documentation-Button"
        href={`${BASE_DOCS_LINK}/reference/${protocol}/`}
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
        target="_blank"
      >
        Reference Docs
      </a>
  );
}

<RadioButtonGroup name="connectionProtocol" >
  <RadioButton
    key="Content-Protocol-RadioButton-http"
    label={`HTTPS Device API ${this.referenceDocsLink('http')}`}
    name="protocol-http"
    value="http"
  />
  <RadioButton
    key="Content-Protocol-RadioButton-mqtt"
    label={`MQTT ${this.referenceDocsLink('mqtt')}`}
    name="protocol-mqtt"
    value="mqtt"
  />
</RadioButtonGroup>
```

UI Renders like this:

[image]

Comment: It's because the `label` prop only accepts a string. So it won't render the JSX you insert, instead it will render [object Object] because in reality it is getting a React.createElement object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to insert JSX into the label prop instead of a string:

```
<RadioButton
    key="Content-Protocol-RadioButton-http"
    label={<div>HTTPS Device API {this.referenceDocsLink('http')}</div>}
    name="protocol-http"
    value="http"
  />
```

But that all depends on if the `RadioButton` accepts JSX as a prop value type or not.

Comment: It looks like it does accept JSX.  Added in your example (switched the `<div>` for a `<span>`) and it worked like a charm.  Thanks!!

Comment: I'm generating RadioButtons dynamically. Although links appear perfectly fine, but when i try to click them, nothing happens except the radio button is selected.
I'm using `material-ui v0.21`. Any ideas?